# What is the Rust way of using continue from inside a closure?

Tags: rust

This isn't possible, but very much desired:

```
loop {
    something().unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        warn!("Something bad happened: {}", err);
        continue;
    });

    // other stuff
}
```

What is the Rust way of solving it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`unwrap_or_else` is just a convenience method around a `match` usually used in method call chains. As this is not the case here, you can simply use a `match` instead, and since you only seem to be interested by the `Err` case, you can also use `if let`:

```
loop {
    if let Err(err) = something() {
        warn!("Something bad happened: {}", err);
        continue;
    }

    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To be explicit, unless I misunderstand @mcarton's answer, the match statement for continuing on an error and keeping a result if not:

```
fn looper() {
  loop {
    let res = match subcommand() {
        Ok(v) => v,
        Err(e) => {
          warn!("Uh oh: {}", e);
          continue;
        }
    }
    ...  // `res` is usable here, unwrapped.
  }
}

// For demonstration only - types may vary
fn subcommand() -> Result<String> {
  ... // some code that returns either Ok(some_string) or Err(msg)
}
```

And that there is not really a way to shorthand it more than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you do NOT need the error variable think this is probably a more elegant and cleaner solution:

```
loop {
   let Ok(_) = something() else {continue};
}
```

Comment: This soultion didn't exist back when this question was asked (not saying this is not a good solution).